# how to download image from amazon S3 bucket using access and secret key in php?

Tags: php, url, amazon-s3, download

I have stored images on amazon S3 server. I want to get download image link(url) for that.
i am using php and used

> $s3-> getAuthenticatedURL($bucketName);

but its output is not improper link for download

And i want to download image with the help of access key and scret key in the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library you are using, but these are the instructions for using the official AWS SDK for PHP: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#creating-a-pre-signed-url